# Undefined index: in .../Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to add a message (store in my BDD for a user to read it later) every time an administrator delete one of his coment.

I decided to use event listerner on doctrine PostRemove listener.

this works fine when I delete only one coment at a time. but if I delete more than one then I got the following message:

**Undefined index: 0000000035772b14000000017d26f374 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php**

**THE LISTERNER**

```
truc.doctrine.notification:
    class: Sdz\BlogBundle\DoctrineListener\TraductionDeleteMessage
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postRemove }
```

.

```
class TraductionDeleteMessage
{
   public function postRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
   {
      $coment = $args->getEntity();

      if (!$Coment instanceof Coment) {
          return;
      }

     $em = $args->getEntityManager();   
     $message = new Message;
     $message->setContenu('message');
     $em->persist($message);
     $em->flush();
   }
}
```

**THE CONTROLLER**

```
   foreach($liste_coments as $coment) // Objet initial
   {  
      if(false === $article->getComents()->contains($coment))
      {
         $em->remove($coment);
      }
   }
```

Comment: If you remove the flush() call in your listener, it works ?

Comment: if I remove the flush() it doesn't solve the problem. It is even worse as it won't work with just one delete.